# giving me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when casting linqtoentites to linqtoobjects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is what have I done:

my class

```
public class Order
{
  // remove some code for brevity
  public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
  public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Knife> Knives { get; set; }
}
```

View model

**Updated:**

```
public class OrderVm
{
  public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

in my controller

1st attempt: This gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
var tmp = _db.Orders
           .Include("Foo")
           .Include("Bar")
           .Include("Knives")
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(o => new OrderVm
           {
             SomeText = o.Knives.Count().ToString() + " some text here"
           });
```

2nd attempt: Gives me error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

```
var tmp = _db.Orders
            .Include("Foo")
            .Include("Bar")
            .Include("Knives")
            .Select(o => new OrderVm
            {
              SomeText = o.Knives.Count().ToString() + " some text here"
            });
```

So basically, what I need is to perform `.ToString()` when assigning the property (Need to cast from int to string). They say it, convert `LinqToEntities` to `LinqToObjects` by calling `AsEnumerable()` (suggested for displaying rather than `ToList()`) But then when I tried to cast it. It gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` really no idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: updated my question once more.

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet isn't executing the projection in C# code, it's translating that code into SQL code that gets executed on the database end.  The SQL equivalent of the operations you are performing can be performed on `null` values and will simply propagate `null` rather than crashing the query.

The first query executes the code in the C# application, using C# operations and null-handling behavior, namely that it throws an exception when trying to call a function on a `null` value rather than propagating null`.

If you can perform the projection on the database end you probably should, as it will prevent you from needlessly passing unneeded information along the wire to the application.  If you perform the projection on the C# end you'll need to code it such that it can properly handle `null` values without crashing.

Comment: What do you suggest? Because I have property in `OrderVm` that I need to cast to a `string` for concatenation purposes.

Comment: @BoyPasmo You need to figure out what is null, and either ensure that it's populated with a valid value, or not perform the given operation on it if it's `null`, depending on whether or not `null` is a valid value in context.